# Agora React-native functional component implementation

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am trying to implement agora video-call using functional component in react-native and getting the engine is not defined error. I am new to react hooks, can someone help.
Below is the code for it:
Declaring Engine -> let engine;

```js
const init = async() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      // Request required permissions from Android
      requestCameraAndAudioPermission().then(() => {
        console.log('requested!');
      });
    }
  }

  const createEngine = async() => {
    console.log("inside engine");
    try{
      console.log("inside try");
      engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
      //await setEngine(e);
      console.log(engine);
      await engine.enableVideo();
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }

useEffect(() => {
    init();
  },[]);

useEffect(() => {
  createEngine();
},[createEngine]);
```

```
The engine variable becomes undefined.
```

Comment: You need to store and update your engine variable through a useState hook.

Answer (score 1):

You are using asynchronous functions, so there is always going to be a period of time where the `engine` is `undefined` before it is ready. The important thing is that your component is able to know whether or not you're got an `engine` and render itself accordingly.

Since `engine` is a variable that changes, you need to control it through a `useState` hook.  React will re-render your component whenever the state changes, but it can't do that with `let engine`.  I am setting the initial value to `undefined` but it could be `null` or something else.  We will call `setEngine` when the engine is ready.

```
const [engine, setEngine] = useState(undefined);
```

When declaring dependencies for a `useEffect`, you want to make sure that you are not depending on functions which get re-created on each render.  You can use memoization techniques such as `useCallback` and `useMemo`, but here I am just moving the `createEngine` function inside the `useEffect` in order to avoid issues.  You might want to do the same with `init`.

```
export const MyComponent = ({ appId }) => {
    // engine state
    const [engine, setEngine] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        // variable used by cleanup function
        let isSubscribed = true;

        // create the function
        const createEngine = async () => {
            console.log("inside engine");
            try {
                console.log("inside try");
                const rtcEngine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
                console.log(rtcEngine);
                await rtcEngine.enableVideo();
                // need to prevent calls to setEngine after the component has unmounted
                if (isSubscribed) {
                    setEngine(rtcEngine);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }

        // call the function
        createEngine();

        // return a cleanup
        return () => { isSubscribed = false; }

    },
        // will run once on component mount or if appId changes
        [setEngine, appId]
    );

    /* ... your init ... */

    return (
        <View>
            {engine // check if we have an engine and not undefined
                ?
                <SomeEngineComponent engine={engine} /> // if we know that we have an engine, we can do something with it
                :
                <SomeLoadingComponent /> // show a loading component while waiting for createEngine to finish 
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried this out before as well using engine and setEngine, while using the engine variable in a function on a button press, I get engine as undefined even though inside the useEffect, it creates the engine correctly, any ideas why?

Comment: The `engine` will always start out as `undefined` until the effect calls `setEngine`.  That's why we need to check the `engine` variable before using it.  I am using the ternary operator for this: `engine ? (if true) : (if false)`.  Do you mean that `setEngine` is never being called?  Or are you using the `engine` variable without checking it?

Comment: Yeah, I mean that setEngine has been called, I am able to print the variable but get that value as undefined in a different function.

Comment: `await engine.joinChannel(
      token,
      channelName,
      null,
      100
    );`

Comment: That sounds like an issue of a "state closure" where the function `startCall` uses the value of `engine` at the time the function was created rather than at the time it was called.

Comment: So, on a button press if I call a function that only has the above mentioned code, should it not take the updated value of the engine?

Comment: It depends on where the function is created and if it gets re-created on each render or not.  If it gets re-created then it should get the current value of `engine` but that also means that any components which take `startCall` get re-rendered with the new callback.  There are ways to avoid causing re-renders down the tree with refs and `ref.current` but that's pretty advanced and probably not necessary.  Can you post a CodeSandbox?

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue, was setting the engine without configuring the listeners, hence it was returning undefined, thanks for all your help, helped me figure out the mistake.